# How to create a new album and move photos into it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I've uploaded a bunch of photos to the following Facebook group:

https://www.facebook.com/groups/Datsville/photos/

However, most of them are not inside any album.

How do I create a brand new album and move the photos into it?

Answer (score -1):

Click on Fotos -> on the top right is a button "Create Album"

Move Fotos in that album.

Comment: I don't see a button. Could you post a screenshot? If it matters, I am browsing using Chrome.